# pyside QSqlTableMode() cannot find table from database from sqlite

Tags: python, qt, sqlite, qt4, pyside

I am using PySide to get Qt bindings in python. The problem I am having is that it cannot find the table name after connecting to the database. First, I have added the database using QSqlDatabase and also setting the name to the sqlite database file. After that I created a QSqlTableModel and set the table to be one of the tables inside my database. When I do that, nothing shows up. By calling the lastError() function it says that the table was not found. I know the connection to the database is good because db.open() returns true. I manually looked into the database file and there are indeed tables with that specific name in it. One thing that I find interesting is that the pointer to the database is different between the QSqlDatabase and the QSqlTableMode(). Is this supposed to happen? The pointers are different but the name are (The ones that says drivers = ..., database =...., etc)

What could be the issue? Here is how I am setting it up.

```
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName("test.db")
    print str(db.open())
    print str(db.database())

    model = QSqlTableModel()
    model.setTable("AntennaModels")
    model.select()
    print str(model.lastError())
```

Here is what prints out when I use db.database() and model.database()

```
<PySide.QtSql.QSqlDatabase(driver=""QSQLITE"", database=""test.db"", host="""", port=-1, user="""", open=true)  at 0x104bf73b0>
<PySide.QtSql.QSqlDatabase(driver=""QSQLITE"", database=""test.db"", host="""", port=-1, user="""", open=true)  at 0x104bf73f8>
```

Comment: That relative database path looks dubious: try using an absolute path.

Comment: Hmm, it worked with absolute path. Is there a way that I can use relative pathing? I know that the database will always be in the same location as the current file so I thought just specifying the name would be sufficient.. I guess not. I would like it to be portable so I can easily package up.

Comment: `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.absdir(__file__)), 'test.db')`.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the built in functions that python corrects. Just a little change that it is os.path.abspath and not os.path.absdir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with `QSqlDatabase` not finding the correct database. Originally, I thought that by just listing the name it which search the file's current directory for the database. This is not seem the case. As suggested by ekhumoro, I set it up using an absolute path. To make this portable between different machine, I've used the python's find file functions to get the absolute path and then append the database item there.